# Text is not displaying properly, how do I fix it?

Tags: html, text, encoding

For the last couple of days my browser Chrome and then Firefox after I downloaded it (importing things from Chrome may have cause the problem there) have been displaying text improperly. I get ? in diamonds in place of some characters (symbols in other languages sometimes, commas and other symbols other times.) Also some text in CSS pages gets replaced E, these Es also show up on in links. Those links seem to display as HTML codes rather than links.

http://i224.photobucket.com/albums/dd150/ErikoKatsuragi/problem1_zpsca93c38a.jpg

http://i224.photobucket.com/albums/dd150/ErikoKatsuragi/problem2_zps67fe9865.jpg

I would later check internet explorer to find that these problems aren't there. My Browsers are displaying in Unicode. Is there anyway I can fix this myself or should I find a professional?

Comment: The pages you are visitng may not have the correct `<meta charset>` declarations on their pages.

Comment: This question is not programming language related. I'd suggest posting it in a forum specilized to these issues. Or just reinstall your OS.
@dgarbacz: It loads fine in my firefox.

Comment: The HTML of that page seems to be broken. Try disabling all Chrome extensions.

Comment: Except it works fine on other computers. And I have similar encoding problems on other websites. And I wouldn't know anything other sites that I could ask questions about this kind of problem.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall and then again Re-install your browsers!!

Comment: I tried this after reading you suggestion, the same problems are still there.